# Command-line invocation to sort files in a directory into three subdirectories named small, medium, and large based on file size

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, directory-listing

I'm new to the command line and I'm trying to write a command-line invocation to sort files in a directory into three subdirectories named small (0-500KB), medium (500KB-1MB), and large (1MB and more) based on file size. I need to give the directory path as the input and create the output subdirectories if they don't exist.

I just tried this code but I don't get the result I need.

```
find . -type f -exec du -h {} + | sort -r -h
```

Am I doing something wrong? Can someone please help me? Thank You.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm guessing your result is just a list of files and their sizes. The issue with your code is that you're not telling it to do anything with that list. I a script in a file will be easier to debug than a one-liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script separates files on the requirements you've stated. I think you're capable to convert the code to your needs. The script expects as input a directory where the files to sort.

```
#! /bin/bash
MY_DIR=$1
[ ! -z "${MY_DIR}" ] || exit 1

cd ${MY_DIR}
MY_FILES=$(find . -type f -exec du -kh {} +  | sort -h -r)
IFS=$'\n'

mkdir lower_500 lower_1000 higher_1000

for i in ${MY_FILES[@]}; do
    file_size=$(echo $i | grep -oE '^[0-9]*')
    file_name=$(echo $i | grep -oE '[^[[:space:]]*]*$')

    echo file_size=$file_size, file_name=$file_name
    if [ "$file_size" -lt 500 ]; then
        mv $file_name lower_500
    elif [ "$file_size" -lt 1000 ]; then
        mv $file_name lower_1000
    else
        mv $file_name higher_1000
    fi
done

exit 0
```

Generate test data:

```
$ mkdir test
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=test/a.img bs=1K count=100
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=test/b.img bs=1K count=520
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=test/c.img bs=1K count=1020
```